# Convert HTML element non-px dimensions to px in (IE issue)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, pixel

I'm trying to get border width of a particular element.
Getting border width style setting is pretty easy by simply reading if from current calculated style of an element:

```
var styles = (
    document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle ?
    document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(de, null) :
    de.currentStyle
);
```

Reading a particular border value is then rather simple by:

```
var top = styles.borderTopWidth;
var value = parseFloat(top);
```

This is all fine and dandy (as long as you **don't use IE**) and I can get top border width in the `value` variable. But this number relates to pixels **only when border width was set in pixels**. If it wasn't (was `em` for instance) than `value` has the number of that particular dimension.

I have to get an answer to any of these two questions:

1. How do I always get border width in pixels?
2. How do I calculate different units into pixels?

### Example

I've prepared a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/46q9b/) where you can see various dimensions reported by DOM and jQuery. Run it in different browsers and you'll see the difference in IE. All dimansions in Crome are in integer values while Firefox calculates margin and padding in floats while border in integers.

BTW: Margin, border and padding are all set to **2mm**.

Comment: Whats the usecase of using anything other then pixel unit for border widths? Using em for border widths seems a little odd to me...

Comment: @BGerrissen: If you'd have a CSS style definition that's also used for printing it wouldn't be anything unusual to use other units like `pt` or `mm` or something similar. That would make perfect sense for printing.

Comment: Mind if I ask why your print styles and screen styles are mixed up? Usually it's best to keep a seperate screen.css and print.css and use media="screen" and media="print" respectively. This solves a lot of JS problems for ya and allows you to write a lot less code to mitigate the painful css mashup you appearantly have.

Ofcourse, I only know what you tell me, you might actually have a justifiable usecase, in which case ignore my comment ;)

Comment: @BGerrissen: I don't but since I'm writing a [plugin](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html) that will have to be adoptable to other user's bad habits, it will have to work either way. And this particular plugin has to check whether certain element is scrollable. But that's a different story. I'll update plugin's code when I adjust my code for `:scrollable` jQuery selector filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most libraries solve this problem for you, as does YUI3 for example.
If you don't want to use those libraries, then at least you can peak at how they do it ;)

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/dom-style-ie.js.html

Awnser contained therein.

Comment: As much as I understand the stuff of YUI it seems it sets particular dimension to `style.right` but in my case I still read non pixel dimension from it. But even though setting other styles would flicker elements wouldn't it?

Comment: Tbh. take my advice, trying to solve this with javascript will become a viscious cycle, the more I think about solutions, the more problems I can think of as well. Changing your stylesheet strategy will net the cleanest, shortes, easiest result.

Comment: (+1 and accepted) This Dean Edwards trick to calculate pixel dimension is a hack and I wonder if it moves an element around, because we set it's position. What if the element was absolutely positioned? Is there any test that can prove this?

Comment: Are you implying that I should simply ignore other dimensions and just assume everything's in pixels?

Comment: CSS Borders, margins, paddings should always be defined in pixels for screen, element dimensions can be in pixels or percentages, but percentage to pixel is easier to calculate if you keep other stuff in pixels. For your print stylesheet you can go nuts with whatever unit you like, JavaScript doesn't do anything with those style rules as they are only rendered at the print prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally get computed pixel sizes using element.offsetWidth and element.offsetHeight.  This is somewhat sensitive if you want to support a range of browsers.  In that case, use a library.  For example, using jQuery you can get guaranteed pixel dimensions with something like this: jQuery("#theID").width().

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that I'd like to get height/width **without** borders (because they're calculated in the value). But then you'd say: *ok use clientHeight/clientWidth then" which is not right, because it doesn't include scrollbars... So i have to use outerHeight and subtract borders from it to get actual visible dimension. And the idea is to **not use any library**.